# Joomla update gone wrong

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

I tried to update my Joomla site (www.thecolourchangers.nl) to Joomla3.6.5 via the update button and the site has made a backup.

The trouble is: nothing is working anymore.

I have unpacked the /tmp folder from the FTP and uploaded the backup files to the FTP root, but that didn't fix it.

Then I deleted the cache folder from FTP; still not fixed.

I have a log file from the update. But nothing works anymore.

Can somebody give some guidance?

Comment: When you say nothing works can you explain what is happening. Is the front end or back end just a white screen? Do you have access to the configuration.php in your root joomla directory to change the Error reporting level or put the site into Maintenance Mode?

Comment: www.thecolourchangers.nl is the website. i cant enter administrator. The site has a error screen. And yes with the FTP i have acces to everything.

Comment: What version of Joomla was it before the update and what is it now?

Comment: Joomla version : 3.6.5 is the version now.

Comment: What version was it before?

Comment: What did you use to take the back up? Akeeba? Did you use Akeebas Retore site or just unpack the file?

Comment: There is a lot of missing detail in your question.  I have tried to improve your English, but I can't add the vital details.  Please be very detailed when describing how your site is "not working". The more diagnostic info you give, the better, faster, and more detailed our support can be.

Answer (score 1):

This is from a article I wrote for my website about how to get past the white screen of death and it should have enough details for you to get something meaningful displayed about your underlying problem.

...

If your Joomla website is now a whitepage in the browser with no obvious reason as to why then read on to learn a couple of simple things you can do to point you in the right direction for getting your website back on line.

The most likely reason you are getting an empty white page where your website used to be is that an error has occurred and because you have Error Reporting set to not display(which is the best way to be from a  security point of view) in your configuration/global settings then Joomla will display the whitepage with no error message. The tips here will help show you have to change the configuration file manually so the error message is displayed and you will have a better idea what has happened.

First step is to get to your configuration.php via your hosting account so you can change the settings to display the error message that is being suppressed.

If your website is down you can't change the settings via the Global Configuration so you need to have the Userid and Password for the account where your Joomla site is hosted. The most popular hosting service is probably cPanel, while Plesk or Webadmin is pretty common or for some of the bigger hosting companies they may have their own interfaces for managing your website hosting. Once you are logged in to your Hosting account you need to find your way to the File or Directory Manager.

Using the file manager find your way to the root or base directory/folder of your website and look for the file configuration.php and open it for Edit. You may like to take a copy or back up of the file just in case, depending on how lucky you feel.

Scroll through the configuration.php file and look for the following lines with;

public $error_reporting='none', and change that to $public error_reporting='maximum',

public $gzip='1', and change it to public $gzip='0', . This may not be required, but for my hosting accounts error reporting fails when gzip is active.

You may also like to change the public $offline='0', to public $offine='1', to display a meaningful messge, public $offline_message = 'Back soon', while you work on your problem.

Now you can Save the configuration.php file and refresh your website page and the whitepage of death should now have a message describing what line of code has failed. You might be tempted to not change Error Reporting back to None, but that can put your website at risk from malicious activity who may deliberately cause an error to see your account name and file structure

Once your website is up and running  you will have access to the Administrator Global Configuration settings you can change the above settings under the first tab and the Server tab.

Comment: After to this, i get a error:

Fatal error: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin' not found in /var/www/vhosts/135/332081/webspace/httpdocs/plugins/system/sessiongc/sessiongc.php on line 23

so i changed this dir to .bak. after that a next error comes up

Fatal error: Class 'JComponentRouterRulesMenu' not found in /var/www/vhosts/135/332081/webspace/httpdocs/components/com_privacy/router.php on line 35

Comment: You need to rename that dir? back to what it was before and resolve that message properly. It appears as if you have mixed versions of core Joomla files.

Comment: Do you have a file ..\libraries\src\Plugin\CMSPlugin.php ?

Comment: Found the problem, i had Joomla 3.9.6. And after the upgrade when wrong i push manually 3.6 on it.. 

I was in the beginning of the website so i deleted everything and start over. 
Thank you.

Comment: I found the problem. I have done a fresh installation of Joomla 3.9.6. Then I installed a purchased Template. And then done the fast install via Akabee. However, he then changed the version of Joomla to 3.4.4. I then performed the update to 3.6.5 via the update button. But after that it all went wrong. No idea what happened.

I have now done an install version and I have to do it all over again. This is not a problem. \

Thank you very much for all the effort.

Comment: @LarsAltorf if this answer was helpful to you I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer so that it at least shows your issue has been resolved and no further action is likely. It is not compulsory to accept an answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, but it does help encourage people like me to take the time to answer more questions for other people.