# Can't access websites hosted on GCP after updating joomla core

Tags: joomla-3.x

I host multiple Joomla sites on a Single Google Computer Engine VM. It has been working very well, but after I performed a Joomla core update I suddenly found that those websites can't be accessed anymore. All websites show "Error" after inputting the domains in the URL.

Here are my websites:

- ajj-glass.com
- uber.ajj-glass.com
- business.ajj-glass.com

Although I can't access the URL, I can connect the directory of websites with FTP and SSH client.

Other information:
Joomla Version: 3.9.13;
Hosting: GCP VM;
Server: Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2, MariaDB and PHP7.2

Can anyone help me to diagnose and/or fix this problem?

Comment: I have answered with some basic steps in response to this earlier issue on JSE which should get your sites displaying more useful information that you can use to further diagnose what the problem might be.

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24733/joomla-update-gone-wrong/24734#24734

Comment: I'm able to access all of those websites. It looks like the problem is already resolved